# Does `Do I Know him` in the US sound like `Do I Know herm`?

Tags: american-english

Does `Do I Know him` in the US sound like `Do I Know herm`?

Google translation speak like `Do I Know him`,and the link of 
[Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=zh-TW&text=Do%20I%20Know%20Him)

It's the last word so it's not `connected speech`.it confuse me when speaking `him`   and `herm`?

Comment: Do you mean that you hear “herm” in the automated pronunciation of “him” that the link takes us to?  Because that’s not what I hear. I hear “him” / hɪm /. And I don’t even speak English with an American accent. By “herm” do you mean you hear a neutral vowel:  / həm / ?  I would indeed expect to hear something like, “Do I know ’əm?” in fast conversation, but that isn’t what the automated voice says.

Comment: In the following video the first person speaking says (at 0:35) “...I can’t speak for how the rest of the world relates to **him**...”. Here the word **him** is pronounced with a neutral vowel / həm / and this may be what you mean by “herm”. https://youtu.be/U7sOH-uYH84

Comment: @OrbitalAussie thanks,you're right. could u answer below,i'll mark it answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. You understand that the usual pronunciation in American English might differ from the pronunciation in automated translation services. We hear “him” / hɪm / in the automated translation but something more like “herm” (with a neutral vowel / həm / ) is what we expect to hear in connected speech in the typical American accent. In rapid conversation you may also hear, “Do I know ’əm?”.

To illustrate this, in [this video](https://youtu.be/U7sOH-uYH84) the first person speaking says (at 0:35) “...I can’t speak for how the rest of the world relates to him...”. Here the word “him” is pronounced with a neutral vowel / həm /.

This may be a *common* American pronunciation but is not the *only* possible pronunciation in all American dialects and in all contexts.  It is also worth noting that a neutral vowel in this situation is a common feature of some other English dialects including Australian English.